# When to say 'dog', and when to say 'hound'?

Tags: word-usage, difference

When refrerring to *Canis lupus familiaris*, what word is better to use, **dog** or **hound**? Wikipedia translates it as **dog**, but I've heard also the word **hound** in many contexts, and that version is a lot easier for me to remember because it resembles the German **hund**.

I think the word **hound** is older and Germanic in origin, but it was later replaced by **dog**, and now it's used mostly in poetry expressions such as **hounds of hell**. Am I right?

Comment: I think a hound is a dog of hunting breeds. It's hard to call a York "hound"...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use *dog*.

*Hound* has a very specific connotation of being a hunting dog, and unless you're specifically referring to one, *dog* is the general term. In addition, by virtue of being the general term, *dog* is much more common, which only further emphasizes how unusual it is to hear *hound* except outside the context of hunting dogs.

> I think the word hound is older and has Germanic origin, but it was later replaced by the dog, and now it's used most in poetry expressions such as hounds of hell. Am I right?

Both *hound* and *dog* come from Proto-Germanic through Old and Middle English, and [Google NGrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dog%2Chound&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) suggests that with the exception of a few years around 1700, *dog* has been more common since at least 1500. Data is sparse the further you go back in time, though, so I can't say for certain how true this is.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hound

Comment: Apparently, according to wiktionary, _dog_ meant _hound_ and _hound_ meant _dog_ in Middle English

Answer (score 3):

Use *hound* when you're being an eighteenth century upper-class country gentleman.

Use *dog* otherwise.

Comment: Also, if you want to "release the...", you release the hounds instead of the dogs.

Comment: @cpast Indeed; with dogs, of course what you do is "let out"